# Two Colors on same link between node in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

How to put two colors on the same link between nodes.

*Here I need to put different color on link what I mentioned before with respect of value*.

This color can place on two sides of the link.

So Half link one color and another half another one color.

So Please help me to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [SVG gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) to do this. Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421) using D3. The idea is to have a hard stop in the middle so it looks like two separate colours and not a gradient. The code would look something like this.

```
var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
  .append("svg:linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "0%");

gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "green")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "50%")
    .attr("stop-color", "green")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "50%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

You can use it exactly like in the example.

Comment: thank you. I tried it. Its working good. But i need to put different event on a line with respect of color . Is that is Possible.And color changing when i drag node. example http://jsfiddle.net/manimegala/PTA4S/ (or) any other way to get my target output.

Comment: For that you will need two separate lines.

Comment: Yes, see e.g. [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/fSvS0fGYBjA).